# <amp-list> only supports external json. How to consume local json?

Tags: amp-html

I am experimenting with the  component to use local json, like in the following example:

```
<div>
  <amp-list layout=fill>
    <script type="application/json">
      {"items":[{"name":"John"},{"name":"Paul"},{"name":"George"},{"name":"Ringo"}]}
    </script>
    <template type="amp-mustache">
      <div>
        Beatles musician: {{name}}
      </div>
    </template>
  </amp-list>
</div>
```

I am getting the following error:

> The mandatory attribute 'src' is missing in tag 'amp-list'. Learn more.

It seems that  only support external json.

How can I consume local (inline) json in AMP?

Answer (score 2):

3 years later, but just in case someone encounters this and wonders this as well: according to the [amp-list documentation](https://amp.dev/documentation/components/amp-list/?format=websites#initialization-from-amp-state), you can use `src="amp-state:YOUR_STATE"` as a way to target a locally set state.

Answer (score 1):

If the json is available at the time the document is generated, it is preferred that you simply resolve the template on the server side. One of AMP's principles is to do work at the appropriate layer, which in your case is on the server rather than in the user's browser.

There is no way to have the AMP runtime do what you are asking, the `src` attribute is mandatory and must be an `https` URL.

Comment: The server has the information, but not the design. The design is customized by the front-end developer, which is the user of our e-store platform.

That's why we would like to provide the information in json. The HTML markup would be customized by the user, using <amp-list> and a <amp-mustache> template.

My suggestion is to make <amp-list> also support local json, like the <amp-analytics> component does.